# How to get href value/url from a javascript function and redirect to it?

Tags: javascript, href

I am trying to redirect to a hostname which is coming as part of request after appending https:// to this.

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:createDynamicPubUrl();" >
```

Below is the function to create a url by appending hostname with protocol(https) :

```
function createDynamicPubUrl() {
     publisherHostName = document.getElementById('hostname').value;
     var pubUrl ;
     var protocol = 'https://';
     pubUrl = protocol+publisherHostName;
     return pubUrl;
}
```

Instead of redirecting to `pubUrl` it is printing the `pubUrl` on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect using `window.location.href` :

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:window.location.href = createDynamicPubUrl()" >link</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to HTTPS is better done on the server side. If however you want to redirect to the HTTPS version on the client side, you can use `window.location.href`:

```
function createDynamicPubUrl() {
    publisherHostName = document.getElementById('hostname').value;
    var pubUrl ;
    var protocol = 'https://';
    pubUrl = protocol+publisherHostName;
    return pubUrl;
}

window.location.href = createDynamicPubUrl();
```